# How can I link to a page outside of my wordpress directory?

Tags: html, wordpress, apache

Ok, so I've got my main site pages in the root directory, so it's basically like so:

```
/index.html
/contact.html
/blog (wordpress directory)
```

I only wanted wordpress to manage the blog pages of the website, but I wanted the wordpress page to match the header from the other pages on the site, so I added the basic header to the `header.php` section and I think that's okay. Inside the header are the links to the rest of the pages on the site (so Home, Contact, etc.).

Linking from the `index.html` or `contact.html` is easy, as I can just link to `blog` and the site goes to the wordpress blog page.

The problem is when I come to try to link back to `index.html` from inside the wordpress site. If I try to link, it will go to `/blog/index.html` (which doesn't exist, so I get a 404 error).

I looked [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website) and saw the HTML tag:

```
<base href="http://myexample.com" />
```

I'm using wordpress installed on a local Apache server, so I tried using `localhost` but that didn't seem to do anything.

What can I do to link outside of the blog directory to get back to my normal pages?

Comment: Not sure how you are "linking back", but have you tried  /index.html.  Notice the / which says to start at the root of your website.

Comment: Have you tried using the "../" pretext?  If you linked  to "../index.html" that will go UP one directory and look for the page index.html.  You can do this for as many folders that you have. i.e. ../../../index.html - This will go UP 3 folders and look for index.

Comment: Wow, I thought I'd tried that, but I saw no harm in trying again and it worked =/ Thank you.

Comment: @Gary's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have you tried just linking to the full url? So instead of "/index.html" just link to "www.yoururl.com"?

Comment: The answer was simple, just /index.html. I thought I'd tried that before asking but obviously I hadn't, or I'd done something else wrong.